# removing a child in actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to make my game restart but I have a few issues. I'm making a asteroids game (basic). I have the following classes :

`GameClass`, `Ship`, `Enemy`.

`Enemy` and `Ship` is created within `GameClass`. `GameClass` is created within the `DocumentClass`(this being the main class).

When the game starts, I start the game e.g.

```
var something:GameClass = new GameClass(); 
addChild(something);
```

The game plays as it should. When I try to remove the objects, nothing happens .. I do it like this:

`something = null` or tried `removeChild(something);`

neither work. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky to tell exactly what's going on from your question without posting more code.  But, doing removeChild(something) seems to be on the right track.  I'm guessing that when you're calling `removeChild(something)` "something" is out of scope.  Maybe try making "something" a private variable within your DocumentClass

Answer (score 0):

In action script, deletes are only deleting refences. So i suggest you delete the entire stage (or movieClip) holding the content to update, and your gameClass(), and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are accidentally creating multiple instances of the GameClass. Have you tried iterating through all of the children of the DocumentClass?

try this from the DocumentClass:

```
for( var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++ )
{
    trace( getChildAt( i ) ); 
    // or removeChild( getChildAt( i ) ) to simply get rid of them.
}
```

If you're using CS3-5, I have personally noticed some very bizarre behavior which has been caused by "automatically declare stage instances". You might want to see what happens if you turn that off.

Comment: When i try to remove the mainclass using removeChild(something), i get this error? ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at DocumentClass/onAvatarDeath()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at Engine/update()

I dont quite understand the error =/

Comment: @michael *sigh* Yea, Flash does that. Unfortunately removeChild does not do null tests and sometimes scope breaks( for lack of a better term ). Try putting: `if( getChildIndex( something ) > -1 ) removeChild(something);` Your other option: `if( something && something.parent ) something.parent.removeChild( something );`

Comment: I've tried the first line and i get the same error, trying the second - nothing seems to happen =/, should i attempt to manually remove all items from 'something' and then remove something? (kinda long but =/)

Comment: Well, that means that clearly something is either already null or something.parent is null. Either way, try tracing all of the children of DocumentClass. Are you sure that you only have one document class? You might accidentally have two. Is DocumentClass the root?

Answer (score 0):

pull the var out so you have access to it throughout the document class.

like this.

```
package src
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
    {
        // You will have access to this var any place in this class.
        private var game:GameClass;

        public function DocumentClass()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initDocumentClass);
        }

        private function initDocumentClass(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initDocumentClass);

            game = new GameClass();
            addChild(game);


            // Now whenever you want to reset your game you can do a few things
            // the easiest would be
            removeChild(game);
            game = new GameClass();
            addChild(game);
        }
    }
}
```

This will also give you easy access via your menu system etc.

Any questions or if I completely missed your point. Just ask.